# Variable \hspace value in relation to outside margin (Two-sided Memoir)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, memoir, backgrounds

So I have received a great deal of help on this. I myself did not create the code, but I have an additional need.

As you can see from my MWE, I have a long two-sided `memoir` document that has a `background` `rule` indicating the current chapter. My issue is the `\hspace` in this particular code snippet:

```
\newcommand*\VerBar[2]{%
  {\color{#1}\rule{#2}{65pt}}%
  \llap{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{%
    \hspace*{-2.5cm}\raisebox{-1.5cm}[0pt][0pt]{%
      \HUGE\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily\thechapter}%
    }%
  }%
}
```

While the chapter number is perfect as a single digit, double digit chapters need more horizontal space to fit the bleed of my book when printed. Therefore, is there a way to establish an `\hspace` value relative to the margin as opposed to generally in the above snippet? In other words, if I change the `\hspace` it adjusts the chapter number in the same direction whether its on the odd or even page. I wish to bring the number towards the two-sided document's gutter - or to the right on odd pages, and to the left on even pages.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside,openright]{memoir}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ATblue}{rgb}{0,0.65,1}
\usepackage[contents={},opacity=0.5,scale=1,angle=90,hshift=-2.5cm]{background}

\newcounter{mychap}
\pretocmd{\chapter}{\stepcounter{mychap}}{}{}
\newcommand*\VerBar[2]{%
  {\color{#1}\rule{#2}{65pt}}%
  \llap{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{%
    \hspace*{-2.5cm}\raisebox{-1.5cm}[0pt][0pt]{%
      \HUGE\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily\thechapter}%
    }%
  }%
}
\newif\ifBgUse
\newlength\LabelSize
\setlength\LabelSize{1.25cm}
\AddEverypageHook{%
\ifBgUse%
\ifodd\value{page} 
\backgroundsetup{
  position={current page.north east},
  vshift=32.5pt,
  hshift=-\value{mychap}*\LabelSize,
  contents={\VerBar{ATblue}{2.5cm}}%
  }%
\else
\backgroundsetup{
  position={current page.north west},
  vshift=-32.5pt,
  hshift=-\value{mychap}*\LabelSize,
  contents={\VerBar{ATblue}{2.5cm}}%
  }%
\fi%
\BgMaterial%
\fi}

\begin{document}
\BgUsetrue


\Blinddocument

\Blinddocument

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1ST APPROACH

This page checks the page number for even/odd, to decide whether to left or right lap the chapter number.  The distance from the outside edge of the chapter number to the edge of the page is preserved in this approach.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside,openright]{memoir}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ATblue}{rgb}{0,0.65,1}
\usepackage[contents={},opacity=0.5,scale=1,angle=90,hshift=-2.5cm]{background}

\def\mylap#1{\ifodd\thepage\llap{#1}\else\rlap{#1}\fi}
\newcounter{mychap}
\pretocmd{\chapter}{\stepcounter{mychap}}{}{}
\newcommand*\VerBar[2]{%
  {\color{#1}\rule{#2}{65pt}}%
  \llap{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{%
    \hspace*{-2.3cm}\raisebox{-1.5cm}[0pt][0pt]{%
      \HUGE\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily\mylap{\thechapter}}%
    }%
  }%
}
\newif\ifBgUse
\newlength\LabelSize
\setlength\LabelSize{1.25cm}
\AddEverypageHook{%
\ifBgUse%
\ifodd\value{page} 
\backgroundsetup{
  position={current page.north east},
  vshift=32.5pt,
  hshift=-\value{mychap}*\LabelSize,
  contents={\VerBar{ATblue}{2.5cm}}%
  }%
\else
\backgroundsetup{
  position={current page.north west},
  vshift=-32.5pt,
  hshift=-\value{mychap}*\LabelSize,
  contents={\VerBar{ATblue}{2.5cm}}%
  }%
\fi%
\BgMaterial%
\fi}

\begin{document}
\BgUsetrue


\Blinddocument
\setcounter{chapter}{10}
\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

2ND APPROACH

While not exactly what you asked for, you may prefer this approach, which gives the chapter number centered in the blue box, regardless of how many digits.

I use a `\makebox[0pt]{\thechapter}` in which to place the chapter number, which will center the chapter number relative that position specified by the `\hspace`, which I modified to 2.3cm.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside,openright]{memoir}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ATblue}{rgb}{0,0.65,1}
\usepackage[contents={},opacity=0.5,scale=1,angle=90,hshift=-2.5cm]{background}

\newcounter{mychap}
\pretocmd{\chapter}{\stepcounter{mychap}}{}{}
\newcommand*\VerBar[2]{%
  {\color{#1}\rule{#2}{65pt}}%
  \llap{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{%
    \hspace*{-2.3cm}\raisebox{-1.5cm}[0pt][0pt]{%
      \HUGE\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily\makebox[0pt]{\thechapter}}%
    }%
  }%
}
\newif\ifBgUse
\newlength\LabelSize
\setlength\LabelSize{1.25cm}
\AddEverypageHook{%
\ifBgUse%
\ifodd\value{page} 
\backgroundsetup{
  position={current page.north east},
  vshift=32.5pt,
  hshift=-\value{mychap}*\LabelSize,
  contents={\VerBar{ATblue}{2.5cm}}%
  }%
\else
\backgroundsetup{
  position={current page.north west},
  vshift=-32.5pt,
  hshift=-\value{mychap}*\LabelSize,
  contents={\VerBar{ATblue}{2.5cm}}%
  }%
\fi%
\BgMaterial%
\fi}

\begin{document}
\BgUsetrue


\Blinddocument
\setcounter{chapter}{10}
\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Second approach, as you suggest, is far more efficient. Fantastic.